# Exacttarget API how to create a filtered data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions, filters

I already know how to create a data filter, I would like to know how to create a data extension with selected data filter via API call. It should create a new data extension with same schema as the source data extension and import the rows matching the filter (simple filterpart) condition.

I can only find the guide on how to create standard or template-based data extension via API on ET's help site.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to create a Filter Activity to run a filter is not currently exposed in the API. It would be possible to do something similar using Query activities.  It wouldn't auto-create the target DE, that would have to be created first so it probably isn't as slick as you were hoping but is an option:

1. Retrieve existing DataExtension and DataExtensionFields objects for target Data Extension
2. Create new DataExtension object using the information from step 1
3. Create QueryActivity with the necessary filter criteria
4. Perform QueryActivity

Comment: thank you, I did it successfully. One issue is I cannot retrieve DisplayOrder or Nillable properties of a data extension field, it throws an error says "The Request Property(s) IsNillable do not match with the fields of DataExtensionField retrieve". So for the new data extension I cannot 100% copy the schema from original DE

Comment: IsRequired is actually what you are looking for, not IsNillable.  For the order, the field is Ordinal instead of DisplayOrder.

Comment: cool, will use them instead, cheers!